# Cannot find controller

Tags: ros, shadow-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am having trouble simulating the shadow robot in the gazebo simulator.

I receive the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1425897239.729246960, 50.527000000]: Could not load controller 'r_arm_joint_trajectory_controller' because controller type 'robot_mechanism_controllers/JointSplineTrajectoryController' does not exist.
```

The controller r_arm_joint_trajectory_controler is defined in:

part of file: `arm_controller.yaml`

```
r_arm_cartesian_pose_controller:
  type: robot_mechanism_controllers/CartesianPoseController
  root_name: shadowarm_base
  tip_name: palm
  fb_trans:
    p: 20.0
    i: 0.5
    d: 0.0
    i_clamp: 1.0
  fb_rot:
    p: 0.5
    i: 0.1
    d: 0.0
    i_clamp: 0.2

r_arm_joint_trajectory_controller:
  type: robot_mechanism_controllers/JointSplineTrajectoryController
  joints:
    - ShoulderJRotate
    - ShoulderJSwing
    - ElbowJSwing
    - ElbowJRotate
    - WRJ2
    - WRJ1
  gains:
    ShoulderJRotate: {p: 140.0, d: 30.0}
    ShoulderJSwing: {p: 140.0, d: 30.0}
    ElbowJSwing: {p: 140.0, d: 30.0}
    ElbowJRotate: {p: 140.0, d: 30.0}
    WRJ2: {p: 140.0, d: 30.0}
    WRJ1: {p: 140.0, d: 30.0}
```

I have package `ros-indigo-robot-mechanism-controllers` installed. I am running ros indigo on ubuntu 14.04.2.

Nikitas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204536/cannot-find-controller/) by [nikitas350](https://answers.ros.org/users/21812/nikitas350/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Nikitas,

This controller is [unfortunately deprecated](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_mechanism_controllers/JointSplineTrajectoryController) and we haven't had time to update to the new Joint Trajectory Action Controller yet. I reported the [issue here](https://github.com/shadow-robot/sr-ros-interface/issues/201). Pull requests are always appreciated :).

It is still possible to use the simulated arm and hand using direct position targets through the relevant topics as is.

Cheers,

Ugo

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2015-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0